# Dagger using Provides vs creating a custom class

Tags: java, dagger-2

I am new to Dagger and I came across an alternative to @Provides on some Dagger project and it got me thinking if there was any actual difference between the two methods.

Common Code:

```
class DependencyOne {
    @Inject DependencyOne();
}

class DependencyTwo {
    @Inject DependencyTwo();
}
```

Approach 1:

```
class MyClass {
    Resource r;

    @Inject MyClass(DependencyOne d1, DependencyTwo d2) {
        r = Resource.builder().addDependencies(d1,d2).build();
    }

    Resource getResource() {
        return r;
    }
}

@Component interface MyComponent {
    MyClass getMyClass();
}

// Get the resource using
DaggerMyComponent.create().getMyClass().getResource();
```

Approach 2:

```
@Module class MyModule {
    @Provides static Resource getResource(DependencyOne d1, DependencyTwo d2) {
        return Resource.builder().addDependencies(d1,d2).build();   
    }
}

@Component(modules={MyModule.class})
interface MyComponent {
    Resource getResource();
}

// Get the resource using
DaggerMyComponent.create().getResource();
```

Now I know I am probably overthinking this a lot but is there any actual difference between the two approaches, performance or otherwise? Is one of them preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0):

`@Provides` methods and constructor injection is the best practice for Dagger 2. Calling the component directly and asking for individual dependencies like the `Resource` is probably to be minimized.

Say you have a class that you want to be able to use the `Resource`. You write the `@Provides` method for the `Resource`. Then you can write a class like this:

```
@Inject
class ResourceConsumer {

    private final Resource resource;

    @Inject
    ResourceConsumer(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

Because Dagger 2 knows how to provide a `Resource`, it will know how to provide a `ResourceConsumer`. Then you can inject your `ResourceConsumer` wherever you want.